# Geting ID from table in SQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, logout

I am trying to create a logout page using `session_destroy()` but all i get is a blank page.

This is my code about logging in(I assume the problem has to be somewhere here but i am a beginner at this).

What i thought it will work is creating a session for the username since it is used at `isset()` but apparently its not working.

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $dbhost = "";
 $dbuser = "";
 $dbpassword = '';
 $db= 'system_dev';

 mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword);
 mysql_select_db($db);



include 'test.php';
if (isset($_POST['username'] )) {
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$_SESSION['username']=$username;

$sql ="Select * FROM Company WHERE username='".$username."'AND password = '".$password."'LIMIT 1";
$sqlid = "Select CompanyId FROM Company WHERE username='".$username."'";




$result = mysql_query($sql);
$resultid= mysql_query($sqlid) or die('Query failed: '. mysql_error());
while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($resultid,MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $col_value){
        echo  "$col_value\n";
    }
}
$company = mysql_free_result($resultid);
$_SESSION['CompanyId'] = $col_value;
}


if ( mysql_num_rows ($result)==1){

header ("Location: webdesign.php");

exit(); 

}
else {

echo "Invalid input";
exit(); 

}

?>
```

On the code of "logout.php" I have only written this:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 session_destroy();
 header ("website.php");
 ?>
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if the answer is not how it should be. I have read the rules but this is the 2nd post so far. I believe i will get better someday :)

Comment: This: `if ( mysql_num_rows ($result)==1){

header ("Location: webdesign.php");

exit(); 

}` won't work - you're echoing data to the screen above it - `header()` must be called before any output is sent to the browser.

Comment: why do you have 2 `session_start();`?

Comment: i just merged two different files so the code can be easily understood and i forgot one of the session start. editing it now!

Comment: both query's query the same table, so why not use just 1 query?

Comment: if you are getting a blank page, it means you have errors in your code. Turn php error reporting on - place `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your code.

Comment: Didnt notice that i am missing `Location:` Thanks a lot. Problem solved

Comment: Although it is not directly related to your answer, I feel it is important to mention that `mysql_query` should not be used (at least not the way you use it). See [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and consider using PDO (it is quite easy though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Location in your header argument like header("Location: page.php");
you can place this header after you destroyed the session, that should not give any problems.

Answer (score 0):

As Dorco said:

> You should use Location in your header

So the logout function should looks like this:

```
session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
header("Location: login.php");
die();
```

And I strongly suggest you, so not simply insert the post value into the SQL query. That will cause a SQL injection. Use prepare statement instead. [PHP: Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)